# Exclude subdirectories from plato metric tool

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, plato

I'm using the [Plato](https://github.com/es-analysis/plato) tool to analyze my web app.

I'm currently running a command like

```
plato -r -d plato_report server public -x "public/|vendor|js" -t "My App"
```

to generate the report.  The idea is that while I want to include the `server` and `public` folders in the analysis, I want to exclude `public/vendor` and `public/js` entirely.  However, the exclusion doesn't seem to be working - plato includes files from the subdirectories I'm trying to ignore.

This could be a regex problem or a plato problem, and I'm not really sure here.  I've tried other regex exclusion patterns like

```
-x ^public\/(|vendor|js)[a-zA-Z0-9-\.\/_]*
```

but to no avail, even though I think these patterns should match.

Any ideas how to achieve this desired behavior with plato?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use grunt for building your app you could use the Gruntfile for grunt-plato as a guide : https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-plato/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

To exclude directories, your task configuration would look something like this

```
 plato : {
    your_task : {
      src : [ 'src/**/*.js', '!src/vendor/**/*.js' ],
      dest : 'reports'
    }
  }
```

The ![pattern] syntax excludes files from the src list.